# Calculate pi to 5 decimals

Tags: code-golf, math, pi

This comes from http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/20-controversial-programming-opinions/

"Given that Pi can be estimated using the function \$4 \times (1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + \cdots)\$ with more terms giving greater accuracy, write a function that calculates Pi to an accuracy of 5 decimal places."

- Note, the estimation must be done by calculating the sequence given above.

Comment: You should probably add some more rules, otherwise you will get answers like (python) `p=lambda:3.14159`

Comment: Have you seen http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/506/calculate-500-digits-of-pi , which is very similar? At the very least, trig functions should be banned for this problem because they allow for trivial solutions such as this QBASIC program: ?INT(4E5*ATN(1))/1E5

Comment: I think you should require that the algorithm be one of successive approximation: the longer you compute, the closer you get to pi.

Comment: @DavidCarraher, although that's mathematically inevitable using this series, from a numerical analytical point of view it's highly dubious. A slowly converging alternating series is a poster child for loss of significance.

Comment: @PeterTaylor "Slowly converging" is an understatement. It took roughly one million places to attain the desired precision!

Comment: huh, a friend of mine posted something about this problem on facebook last night.  he didn't golf it though.

Comment: Dupe, but it's so old it's not here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/407518/12274

Comment: Later near-duplicate: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22009

Comment: "It can be answered in about 10 lines with c#" someone please beat that

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because use of a specific algorithm is impossible to objectively validate

Answer (score 10):

### JavaScript, <s>46 58 56</s> 45 bytes

*ES6 update*: Turns out there's more features available to us now that five years have passed.

```javascript
let f=(i=0,a=0)=>i>1e6?a:f(i+4,a+8/-~i/(i+3))
```

This version (**45** bytes; yes, the `let` is required) works in ES6 strict mode *in theory*.  In practice, you can run it in V8 (e.g. with node) with `--use-strict --harmony-tailcalls`; the Proper Tailcalls feature isn't widely implemented yet, alas.  However, it's specified behaviour, so it should be fine.

If we want to stick to what's widely implemented, and not require strict-mode, we can simply use the ES6 fat-arrow syntax for functions but otherwise retain the same implementation as before (suggested by Brian H) for a cost of **48** bytes.

```javascript
a=>{for(a=i=0;i<1e6;a+=8/++i/~-(i+=3));return a}
```

The choice of name for the single parameter doesn't *really* matter, but we might as well pick one of the names we use so as to minimise the global-scope pollution.

---

```javascript
function(){for(a=i=0;i<1e6;a+=8/++i/~-(i+=3));return a}
```

This version is a function expression; add two characters (e.g. " `f`") if you want it named.  This version clobbers the globals `a` and `i`; this could be prevented if we added "`a,i`" to the parameter list.

Makes use of a reformulated version of the algorithm in order to circumvent the need for subtraction.

```javascript
 1/1 - 1/3  +   1/5 - 1/7   +    1/9 - 1/11  + ...
(3/3 - 1/3) + (7/35 - 5/35) + (11/99 - 9/99) + ...
    2/3     +      2/35     +       2/99     + ...
  2/(1*3)   +    2/(5*7)    +     2/(9*11)   + ...
```

Here's a "plain" version without this adjustment:

```javascript
function(){for(a=0,i=1;i<1e6;i+=2)a+=[,4,,-4][i%4]/i;return a}
```

which clocks in at <s>*64*</s> **62** characters.

Thanks to @ardnew for the suggestion to get rid of the `4*` before the `return`.

---

#### History

```javascript
function(){for(a=i=0;i<1e6;a+=8/++i/~-(i+=3));return a}     // got rid of `i+=4`; restructured
// Old versions below.
function(){for(a=0,i=1;i<1e6;i+=4)a+=8/i/-~-~i;return a}    // got rid of `4*`
function(){for(a=0,i=1;i<1e6;i+=4)a+=2/i/-~-~i;return 4*a}
```

Comment: o.O  very nice job, factoring out the subtraction.

Comment: great work, but needs to be written as a proper function

Comment: @ardnew: Thanks, I must've missed that detail when I read the problem description.  I've updated it, and it's now a callable function expression (lambda); not sure if this is allowed or if it has to be given a name.  If that's the case, it's just an additional two characters anyway.

Comment: @FireFly you can also shave off 2 chars by changing `a+=2/i/-~-~i;return 4*a` to `a+=8/i/-~-~i;return a`

Comment: @ardnew: oh, awesome; didn't think of that. :D

Comment: using arrow notation you can get it down to this: `a=x=>{for(a=i=0;i<1e6;a+=8/++i/~-(i+=3));return a}` and it's a named function now, to make it anonymous just get rid of the first 2 chars. (x is an unused parameter, it saves one byte against using `()`)

Comment: @BrianH. Heh, this answer predates ES6, so fat-arrow functions didn't exist yet. Hmm, let me ponder this a bit and update with an ES6 version, I have some ideas…

Comment: omg, didnt notice the date lol

Answer (score 8):

### Python 59 bytes

```py
print reduce(lambda x,p:p/2*x/p+2*10**999,range(6637,1,-2))
```

This prints out 1000 digits; slightly more than the required 5. Instead of using the prescribed iteration, it uses this:

```
pi = 2 + 1/3*(2 + 2/5*(2 + 3/7*(2 + 4/9*(2 + 5/11*(2 + ...)))))
```

The `6637` (the innermost denominator) can be formulated as:

```
digits * 2*log2(10)
```

This implies a linear convergence. Each deeper iteration will produce one more binary bit of *pi*.

***If***, however, you insist on using the *tan<sup>-1</sup>* identity, a similar convergence can be achieved, if you don't mind going about the problem slightly differently. Taking a look at the partial sums:

*4.0, 2.66667, 3.46667, 2.89524, 3.33968, 2.97605, 3.28374, ...*

it is apparent that each term jumps back and forth to either side of the convergence point; the series has alternating convergence. Additionally, each term is closer to the convergence point than the previous term was; it is absolutely monotonic with respect to its convergence point. The combination of these two properties implies that the arithmetic mean of any two neighboring terms is closer to the convergence point than either of the terms themselves. To give you a better idea of what I mean, consider the following image:

[image: Partial Sums]

The outer series is the original, and the inner series is found by taking the average of each of the neighboring terms. A remarkable difference. But what's truly remarkable, is that this new series also has alternating convergence, and is absolutely monotonic with respect to its convergence point. That means that this process can be applied over and over again, ad nauseum.

Ok. But how?

Some formal definitions. Let *P<sub>1</sub>(n)* be the *n<sup>th</sup>* term of the first sequence, *P<sub>2</sub>(n)* be the *n<sup>th</sup>* term of the second sequence, and similarly *P<sub>k</sub>(n)* the *n<sup>th</sup>* term of the *k<sup>th</sup>* sequence as defined above.

*P<sub>1</sub> = [P<sub>1</sub>(1), P<sub>1</sub>(2), P<sub>1</sub>(3), P<sub>1</sub>(4), P<sub>1</sub>(5), ...]*

*P<sub>2</sub> = [(P<sub>1</sub>(1) +P<sub>1</sub>(2))/2, (P<sub>1</sub>(2) +P<sub>1</sub>(3))/2, (P<sub>1</sub>(3) +P<sub>1</sub>(4))/2, (P<sub>1</sub>(4) +P<sub>1</sub>(5))/2, ...]*

*P<sub>3</sub> = [(P<sub>1</sub>(1) +2P<sub>1</sub>(2) +P<sub>1</sub>(3))/4, (P<sub>1</sub>(2) +2P<sub>1</sub>(3) +P<sub>1</sub>(4))/4, (P<sub>1</sub>(3) +2P<sub>1</sub>(4) +P<sub>1</sub>(5))/4, ...]*

*P<sub>4</sub> = [(P<sub>1</sub>(1) +3P<sub>1</sub>(2) +3P<sub>1</sub>(3) +P<sub>1</sub>(4))/8, (P<sub>1</sub>(2) +3P<sub>1</sub>(3) +3P<sub>1</sub>(4) +P<sub>1</sub>(5))/8, ...]*

Not surprisingly, these coefficients follow exactly the binomial coefficients, and can expressed as a single row of Pascal's Triangle. Since an arbitrary row of Pascal's Triangle is trivial to calculate, an arbitrarily 'deep' series can be found, simply by taking the first *n* partial sums, multiply each by the corresponding term in the *k<sup>th</sup>* row of Pascal's Triangle, and dividing by *2<sup>k-1</sup>*.

In this way, full 32-bit floating point precision (~14 decimal places) can be achieved with just 36 iterations, at which point the partial sums haven't even converged on the second decimal place. This is obviously not golfed:

```py
# used for pascal's triangle
t = 36; v = 1.0/(1<<t-1); e = 1
# used for the partial sums of pi
p = 4; d = 3; s = -4.0

x = 0
while t:
  t -= 1
  p += s/d; d += 2; s *= -1
  x += p*v
  v = v*t/e; e += 1

print "%.14f"%x
```

If you wanted arbitrary precision, this can be achieved with a little modification. Here once again calculating 1000 digits:

```py
# used for pascal's triangle
f = t = 3318; v = 1; e = 1
# used for the partial sums of pi
p = 4096*10**999; d = 3; s = -p

x = 0
while t:
  t -= 1
  p += s/d; d += 2; s *= -1
  x += p*v
  v = v*t/e; e += 1

print x>>f+9
```

The initial value of *p* begins *2<sup>10</sup>* larger, to counteract the integer division effects of *s/d* as *d* becomes larger, causing the last few digits to not converge. Notice here again that `3318` is also:

```
digits * log2(10)
```

The same number of iteratations as the first algorithm (halved because *t* decreases by *1* instead of *2* each iteration). Once again, this indicates a linear convergence: one binary bit of *pi* per iteration. In both cases, 3318 iterations are required to calculate 1000 digits of *pi*, as slightly better quota than 1 million iterations to calculate 5.

Comment: That's much better than my solution: `4 * sum(1/(1+i*2) if not i%2 else -1/(1+i*2) for i in xrange(places*10**(places)))`

Comment: This is very similar to [my approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143101/58880), which happens to be a different form of yours. In mine, as `k → ∞`, `f(-1,k)` approaches your Euler-sum.

Comment: Very cool; awesome analysis and explanation, thank you.

Comment: Just a small thing. Didn't you mean after the `P_1 = ..., P_2 = ..., P_3 = ..., P_4 = ...`, "...multiply each by the corresponding term in the `kth` row of Pascal's Triangle, and dividing by `2^{k-1}`.", instead of `nth` row and `2^{n-1}`?.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff I did, yes. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica <strike>42 39 34 33 31 26</strike> 32

**Archimedes' Approach** 26 chars

```
N@#*Sin[180 Degree/#]&
```

This reaches the criterion when input is 822.

Question: Does anyone know how he computed the Sin of 180 degrees? I don't.

---

**Leibniz' Approach** (Gregory's series) 32 chars

This is the same function the problem poser gave as an example.
It reaches the criterion in approximately one half million iterations.

```
N@4Sum[(-1)^k/(2k+1),{k,0,10^6}]
```

---

**Madhava-Leibniz Approach** 37 chars

This variation uses a few more characters but converges to criterion in only 9 iterations!

```
N@Sqrt@12 Sum[(-1/3)^k/(2k+1),{k,0,9}]
```

Comment: those all compute it by the algorithm given in the problem definition?

Comment: @acolyte  Leibniz' approach (now the first one listed) is indeed the one mentioned in the description of the problem. It's very slow to converge.  A slight variation on it (Madhava-Leibniz) converges very quickly.

Comment: Sine of 180° is pretty easy.  It's 180°/N that can get tricky outside of the usual suspects for N.

Comment: Please explain, @J.B. Tricky to measure?

Comment: This entry should state "32" because only Leibniz' approach fulfils the requirements (counting the characters in the code as given, I get 34, but both spaces may be safely removed, giving indeed a length of 32).

Comment: @celtschk You appear to be correct.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

### Java (67 chars)

```java
float r(){float p=0,s=4,i=1E6f;while(--i>0)p+=(s=-s)/i--;return p;}
```

Note that this avoids loss of significance by adding the numbers up in the correct order.

Comment: this is fully compliant C code too. if posted as C, you could change `while(--i>0)` to `while(i--)` and save 2 chars

Comment: @ardnew, true, but with C there are much more interesting tricks to play...

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 32

```haskell
foldr(\k->(4/(2*k+1)-))0[0..8^7]
```

> GHCi> foldr(\k->(4/(2*k+1)-))0[0..8^7]
>   3.141593130426724

Counting a function name it's

### 34

```haskell
π=foldr(\k->(4/(2*k+1)-))0[0..8^7]
```

Answer (score 4):

### APL (14)

```apl
4×-/÷1-⍨2×⍳1e6
```

Comment: 13, `--/4÷1-2×⍳1e6`

Answer (score 3):

**J, 26 chars**

<strike>+/+/_2((4 _4)&%)>:+:i.100</strike>

Moved from 100 items of sequence to  1e6 items. Also now it's a code tagged and could be copypasted from browser to the console without errors.

```j
+/+/_2((4 _4)&%)\>:+:i.1e6
```

Comment: `-/4%>:2*i.1e6` -- 13 characters. (Thanks to b_jonas in #jsoftware for making me realise that `-/` works to compute a sum with alternating sign.  [This is since all operators in J are of equal precedence and right-associative, so `-/ 1 2 3 4` <=> `1 - (2 - (3 - 4))` <=> `1 - 2 + 3 - 4`.])

Comment: that's neat and twice as awesome. Or even 2^10 more awesome!

Comment: @FireFly that is beautiful

Answer (score 3):

### C (GCC) (44 chars)

```c
float p(i){return i<1E6?4./++i-p(++i):0;}
```

That's 41 chars, but it also has to be compiled with `-O2` to get the optimiser to eliminate the tail recursion. This also relies on undefined behaviour with respect to the order in which the `++` are executed; thanks to ugoren for pointing this out. I've tested with gcc 4.4.3 under 64-bit Linux .

Note that unless the optimiser also reorders the sum, it will add from the smallest number, so it avoids loss of significance.

Call as `p()`.

Comment: Your recursive call is `q()`, not `p()`. And I don't think `-O2` should be counted (but if you do count it, it's 4 chars because of the required space).

Comment: Also: 1. gcc 4.1.1 doesn't optimize the recursion (and I don't see how it could), so the stack overflows. 2. it should be called as `p(0)`. 3. Save a char by `return++i...`. 4. Two `++i` makes undefined behavior.

Comment: @ugoren, thanks for your comments. In order: `q` - that'll teach me to double-check after renaming. I think I'm following normal practice in counting `-O2` as 3 chars, but we can open it up on meta if you want; http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19 is the only relevant discussion I can find. I've added the version of gcc which I'm using, and which allows me to call it as `p()`. Saving the char stops the optimiser and gives segfault. I will clarify that I'm using undefined behaviour, as per http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21

Comment: I added an answer to the meta question about flags. About `p()` - are you sure calling `p()` from any context would work? Or is it just what happened to be on the stack in your test?

Comment: @ugoren, maybe I got lucky consistently. Even if I call it twice in a row, the second one still returns the correct value. gcc does seem to produce slightly different code for `p()` vs `p(0)`, but I don't know what behaviour it documents and I'm not really a C programmer.

Answer (score 3):

### R - 25 chars

```
sum(c(4,-4)/seq(1,1e6,2))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure - 79 chars

```
(fn [](* 4(apply +(map #(*(Math/pow -1 %1)(/ 1.0(+ 1 %1 %1)))(range 377000)))))
```

This creates a function of no arguments which will calculate a float which approximates pi correctly to five decimal places. Note that this does not bind the function to a name such as `pi`, so this code must either be evaluated in place with `eval` as `(<code>)` or bound to a name in which case the solution is

```
(defn p[](* 4(apply +(map #(*(Math/pow -1 %1)(/ 1.0(+ 1 %1 %1)))(range 377000)))))
```

for 82 chars

#### About

```
(defn nth-term-of-pi [n] (* (Math/pow -1 n) (/ 1.0 (+ 1 n n))))
(defn pi [c] (* 4 (apply + (map nth-term-of-pi (range c)))))
(def  pi-accuracy-constant (loop [c 1000] (if (< (pi c) 3.14159) (recur (inc c)) c)))
; (pi pi-accuracy-constant) is then the value of pi to the accuracy of five decimal places
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript - 33 Characters

```
p=x=>4*(1-(x&2))/x+(x>1?p(x-2):0)
```

Call `p` passing a positive odd number `x` and it will calculate Pi with `(x-1)/2` terms.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby - 82 chars

```
def f(n,k=n)k>0?(f(n,k-1)+f(n+1,k-1))/2:n<0?0:f(n-1,0)+(-1)**n/(2*n+1.0)end;4*f(9)
```

Try it : https://repl.it/LQ8w

The approach uses the given series indirectly using a numerical acceleration approach. The resulting output is

`pi ≈ 3.14159265161`

vs.

`pi = 3.14159265359`

It starts with

```
f(n,0) = 1/1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - ... + ((-1)**n)/(2*n+1)
```

And then, since this is alternating, we can accelerate the convergence using

```
f(n,1) = (f(n,0) + f(n+1,0))/2
```

And it repeatedly applies this:

```
f(n,k) = (f(n,k-1) + f(n+1,k-1))/2
```

And for simplicity, `f(n) = f(n,n)`.

---

### Ruby - 50 chars

If you don't mind running for a really long while, then you could simply use

```
def f(n)n<0?0:f(n-1)+(-1)**n/(2*n+1.0)end;4*f(1e7)
```

or

```
a=0;for k in 0..1e7 do a+=(-1)**k/(2*k+1.0)end;4*a
```

Answer (score 2):

## VBA - 80 <strike>105</strike> characters

From the VBE immediate window:

```
s=-1:x=1:i=3:While Left(4*x,7)<>3.14159:x=x+((1/i)*s):s=-s:i=i+2:Wend:Debug.?4*x
```

Using `Left()` instead of `Round()` saves a character but also makes it more accurate to the definition of the challenge.
I'm getting my character count from Notepad++.  I do see that other systems may count differently.

The algorithm below is easier to read:

```
Sub p
    s=-1:x=1:i=3
    While Left(4*x,7)<>3.14159
        x=x+((1/i)*s)
        s=-s
        i=i+2
    Wend
    Debug.?4*x
    Debug.?"Pi to 5 places solved in ";(i-1)/2;" steps."
End Sub
```

*If you want to test this code and have Microsoft Excel, Word, Access, or Outlook installed (Windows only), press Alt+F11 to open the VBA IDE. Insert a new code module (Alt+I,M) and clear out `Option Explicit` if shown at the top. Then paste in the code and press F5 to run it. The results should appear in the Immediate Window (press Ctrl+G if you don't see it).*

Comment: Great solution, but you have some room for improvement. It looks like you have overcounted your solution, as is, I see [97 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYy7DsIgFEB3vuJu0oc12HawEV30B9SkcynY3oSAKRDp11fifB7rIAaH47aD14wORisVfFFrMNbDEkwJ6CGBt10SDMajmUCsXjmwRq/bMwj40Iw4vmdd5KxDXpN@Rq3gkXRJmzyWbXa@1BVrWHsikceCUnbALHf/zBHkWBxJr4wkNyXCVF1TRO5GQrpv2w8) of code. You can also drop the `()` from the sub call. If you are willing to make it an immediate window solution you can further knock it down to `s=-1:x=1:i=3:While Round(4*x,5)<>3.14159:x=x+((1/i)*s):s=-s:i=i+2:Wend:?4*x` for 75 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I wrote a minify algorithm for VBA and have updated it.  I'm guessing that TIO counts CrLf different than Notepad++ but it's not something I am worried about.  I had fun playing this round of code golf.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl - <strike>43</strike> 39 chars

not sure the rules on anonymous subroutines, but here's another implementation using @FireFly's series construction

```perl
sub{$s+=8/((4*$_+2)**2-1)for 0..1e6;$s}
```

```
sub p{$s+=(-1)**$_*4/(2*$_+1)for 0..1e6;$s}
```

Answer (score 1):

### C, 69 chars

```
float p,b;void main(a){b++<9e6?p+=a/b++,main(-a):printf("%f\n",4*p);}
```

- Run with no command line parameters (so `a` is initialized to 1).
- Must be compiled with optimization.
- `void main` is strange and non-standard, but makes things work. Without it, the recursion is implemented as a real call, leading to a stack overflow. An alternative is adding `return`.
- Two characters `4*` can be saved, if running with three command line parameters.

Comment: You could shorten that to `int main(a)` or even `main(a)`, GCC only gives a warning. And it will give a warning for `void main` anyway, and maybe even because you have only one argument to `main`.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP - <strike>56</strike> 55 chars

```php
<?for($j=$i=-1;1e6>$j;){$p+=($i=-$i)/($j+=2);}echo$p*4;
```

I don't know that I can get it much smaller without breaking the algorithm rule.

Comment: How about this for 45? `<?for(;1e6>$j;)$p+=($i=-$i|4)/~-$j+=2;echo$p;`

Comment: I was trying to come up with that, but couldn't get the bitwise ops to work. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You can remove the last semicolon to save 1 character.

Answer (score 1):

### Python - 56 chars

Meh, My python-fu is not strong enough. I couldn't see any more shortcuts but maybe a more experienced golfer could find something to trim here?

```
t=s=0
k=i=1
while t<1e6:t,s,i,k=t+1,k*4./i+s,i+2,-k
```

Comment: You could use Python 3 to save one byte for the float division (`4.` -> `4`). In other news, I just found a case where Python 3 actually beats Python 2 in code golf!

Answer (score 1):

### Python (49)

```
print 4*sum((-1)**i/(2*i+1.)for i in range(9**6))
```

```
3.14159453527
```

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge, 129 bytes

```
p08p109p^v*86%+55:<$$$<
\$\>:#,_@>+\55+/:#^_"."
v>p"~"/:"~"%08p"~"/00p:2\4%-*"(}"
8^90%"~":+2:+g90*+g80*<
>*:**\/+>"~~"00g:"~"`!|
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=cDA4cDEwOXBedio4NiUrNTU6PCQkJDwKXCRcPjojLF9APitcNTUrLzojXl8iLiIKdj5wIn4iLzoifiIlMDhwIn4iLzAwcDoyXDQlLSoiKH0iCjheOTAlIn4iOisyOitnOTAqK2c4MCo8Cj4qOioqXC8rPiJ+fiIwMGc6In4iYCF8&input=)

In case anyone is wondering, it's an elephant.

[image: Cartoon elephant]

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 16 bytes

```
*_4ṁ\↑^9 9z*İ_İ1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv5/eLuhlqEBCDxqavyvFW/ycGdjzKO2iXEmCpZVWkc2xB/ZYPj/PwA) using series of only 6561 (9^4) terms (times-out on TIO for longer series).

Output is a rational number expressed as a fraction: TIO header multiplies by 100,000 and rounds to nearest integer.

```
*_4ṁ\↑^9 9z*İ_İ1
*_4                 # multiply by -4:
   ṁ                # sum of series of
    \               # reciprocals of
     ↑^9 9          # first 387420489 (9^9) terms of
          z*        # pairwise products of
            İ_      # powers of -1 (-1,1,-1,1,...) and
              İ1    # odd numbers (1,3,5,7,9,...)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 34 characters

```
[range(1;1e6;4)|1/.-1/(.+2)]|add*4
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.2$ jq -n '[range(1;1e6;4)|1/.-1/(.+2)]|add*4'
3.1415906535898936
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z@6KDEvPVXD0Now1czaRLPGUF9P11BfQ0/bSDO2JjElRcvk//9/@QUlmfl5xf91dfNKc3J0M/MKSksA)

Answer (score 0):

### Java - <strike>92</strike> 84 chars

I cannot beat by far Peter Taylor's result, but here is mine:

```
double d(){float n=0,k=0,x;while(n<9E5){x=1/(1+2*n++);k+=(n%2==0)?-x:x;}return 4*k;}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
double d() {
    float n = 0, k = 0, x;
    while (n < 9E5) {
        x = 1 / (1 + 2 * n++);
        k += (n % 2 == 0) ? -x : x;
    }
    return 4 * k;
}
```

Edit: Saved a few characters using ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

**Ruby - 54 chars**

```
def a()p=0;1000000.times{|i|p+=8/(4*i*(4*i+2))};p;end;
```

My first try on console

```
def a()i=1;p=0;while i<2**100 do p+=8/(i*(i+2));i+=4;end;p;end;
```

63 chars.

Comment: You can save a byte by using `def a;` instead of `def a()`.

Comment: Another one by removing the last semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

## k (25 chars)

<s>4*+/%(i#1 -1)*'1+2*!i:1000000</s>

Slightly shorter:

```
+/(i#4 -4)%1+2*!i:1000000
```

Comment: Can save 6 bytes by doing `-4*{y-x}/%1+2*!_1e6` (assuming a `k` where monadic `%` is inverse).

Comment: Can trim another byte by doing `{y-x}/-4%1+2*!_1e6` (and avoid the monadic `%` issue).

Answer (score 0):

### Perl (76 chars)

```
$y=1e4;for$x(0..1e4-1){$y--while sqrt($x**2+$y**2)>1e4;$a+=$y}print 4*$a/1e8
```

(Result: 3.14159052)

Not the shortest possible solution, but maybe interesting. It's a geometrical one. I calculate the area under a circle.

I got another funny approach, but it's really slow. It counts the number of discrete points in a square that are below a quarter circle and calculates pi from it:

```
$i=shift;for$x(0..$i){for$y(0..$i){$h++if sqrt($x**2+$y**2)<$i}}print$h*4/$i**2
```

It expects the number of iterations as command line argument. Here you can see how run time relates to accuracy. ;)

```
$ time perl -e '$i=shift;for$x(0..$i){for$y(0..$i){$h++if sqrt($x**2+$y**2)<$i}}print$h*4/$i**2' 100
3.1796
real    0m0.011s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.003s

$ time perl -e '$i=shift;for$x(0..$i){for$y(0..$i){$h++if sqrt($x**2+$y**2)<$i}}print$h*4/$i**2' 1000
3.14552
real    0m0.354s
user    0m0.340s
sys 0m0.004s

$ time perl -e '$i=shift;for$x(0..$i){for$y(0..$i){$h++if sqrt($x**2+$y**2)<$i}}print$h*4/$i**2' 10000
3.14199016
real    0m34.941s
user    0m33.757s
sys 0m0.097s
```

Answer (score 0):

## CJam - 21

```
1e6{WI#4d*I2*)/}fI]:+
```

Pretty straightforward calculation of the given series.
CJam is http://sf.net/p/cjam

Answer (score 0):

## Julia - 30 characters

```
sum(4./[1:4:1e6] - 4./[3:4:1e6])
```

Answer (score 0):

## SQL, 253 bytes

```
DECLARE @B int=3, @A varchar(max), @C varchar(max)='1'
WHILE @B<100000
BEGIN
SELECT @C=@C+(select case when (@B-1)%4=0 then'+'else'-'end)+
(SELECT cast(cast(1.0/@B as decimal(9,8)) as varchar(max)))
SELECT @B=@B+2
END
EXECUTE('SELECT 4*('+@C+')')
```

I would provide a SQL Fiddle, but this goes too many loops deep finding the 1/3 1/5 1/7 etc. fractions and gives errors lol. However, if you change `@B<100000` to `1000` then it runs (obviously not to the same number of digits of accuracy).

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 25 bytes

```
7.?,{2*)2.-1??./\/\-}*)4*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/31zPXqfaSEvTSE/X0N5eTz9GP0a3VkvTROv/fwA)

```
7.?                         # Push 7^7=823543, we just need an odd number bigger than 136120
   ,{               }*      # For every number k from 1 to 823542
     2*)                    # 2*k+1
        2.-1??./            # sqrt(2)/sqrt(2)=1.0 this number is just 1, but it is a float
                \/          # 1.0 / (2*k+1)
                  \-        # Subtract the sequence from this number
                      )     # Add 1 because 1/1 was skipped
                       4*   # Multiply by 4
```

Output:

```
3.141593867855424
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 30 bytes

```
4\sum_{n=0}^{9^6}(-1)^n/(1+2n)
```

[Try it on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nivxhndq6p)

Pretty self-explanatory coding of the sequence. An array-based method, while it sounds like it should be more efficient, runs into Desmos' limitations on array length.

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 20 bytes

```
V4e5{4T2*)d/WT#*+}fT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/P8wk1bTaJMRISzNFPzxEWUu7Ni3k/38A)

One byte shorter than aditsu's answer. ;)

### Alternate 20-byter

```
4_e5,f{_2*)W@#*d/}:+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/3yQ@1VQnrTreSEsz3EFZK0W/1kr7/38A)

Does the same thing, but I like this better for some reason.