# Reducing Leibniz perl code in characters

Tags: code-golf, tips, perl

This Perl code is supposed to calculate the Leibniz formula. [The original problem is here.](https://www.hackerrank.com/codesprint4/challenges/leibniz)

The input format is:

```
T
<T test cases, each on their own line>
```

Each test case is a number < 10^7. The output format should be the same, minus the first line.

For example, an input:

```
2 
10 
20
```

And for output:

```
0.760459904732351
0.77290595166696
```

My first solutions, at 62 and 61 characters respectively.

```
for(1..<>){$s=0;map{$s+=($_&1||-1)/(2*$_-1)}1..<>;print"$s\n"}

for(1..<>){$s=0;$s+=($_&1||-1)/(2*$_-1)for 1..<>;print"$s\n"}
```

Edit: The best solution so far is 53 characters, by @teebee:

```
<>;print${\map$a-=(-1)**$_/(2*$_-1),1..$_},$a=$/for<>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate pi to 5 decimals](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7112/calculate-pi-to-5-decimals)

Comment: Why post the same question on two sites? I feel like it's either *help* or *a puzzle*, but not both. And as a puzzle it needs a puzzle-type ([tag:code-golf], [tag:coding-challenge]) and objective winning criteria.

Comment: I was recommended that this question belongs here more then stackoverflow so posted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Perl 55 bytes

```
<>;map($s-=(-1)**$_/(2*$_-1),1..$_),$s=!print$s,$/for<>
```

Without using any Perl non-standard features (such as `say`). 3 bytes are wasted removing the first value from the input.

Sample usage:

in.dat

```
2
10
20
```

```
$ perl leibniz.pl < in.dat
0.760459904732351
0.77290595166696
```

---

### Alternative, also 55 bytes

```
map{$s-=(-1)**$_/($_*2-1)for 1..<>;$s=!print$s,$/}1..<>
```

The alternative may be run interactively, without requiring an input file. Which, as I understand, is what you meant by running indefinitely.

Comment: That goes in an infinite loop, but using this notation for for can save 2 more bytes `map($s-=(-1)**$_/(2*$_-1),1..<>),$s=!print$s.$/for 1..<>`

Comment: It will only cause an 'infinite' loop if the input given contains an infinite amount of lines. The `for<>` construction will iterate over every line in input passed to STDIN exactly once, without needing to 'know' beforehand how many there are.

Answer (score 5):

## Perl 53 bytes

You can save two more strokes:

```
<>;print${\map$a-=(-1)**$_/(2*$_-1),1..$_},$a=$/for<>
```

Comment: Very clever. One would expect `\map...` to return a single array reference, and not a list of scalar references.