# Solve the CodeSprint4 Leibniz code golf challenge in Python in 66 characters

Tags: code-golf, tips, python, pi

Check out this challenge:

https://www.hackerrank.com/codesprint4/challenges/leibniz

(The competition has already ended, so I'm just curious about the Python solution, which the organizers refused to reveal, so this is not cheating in any way.)

Modified from that page:

> In Calculus, the Leibniz formula for \$\pi\$ is given by:
>
> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^n}{2n+1}$$
>
> You will be given an integer \$n\$. Your task is to print the summation of the Leibniz formula up to the \$n\$th term of the series correct to 15 decimal places.
>
> That is given \$n\$ calculate:
>
> $$\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^k}{2k+1}$$
>
> with the first 15 decimal places correct.
>
> ## Input Format
>
> The first line contains the number of test cases (\$T\$) which is less than 100. Each additional line is a test case for a positive integer value less than 10^7.
>
> ## Output Format
>
> Output \$T\$ lines each containing the calculated result for the corresponding line of the input.
>
> ## Scoring
>
> This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

I only managed to solve the challenge in 77 characters. (Talking only about Python here.) However, one adr2370 managed to solve the challenge in 66 characters!

Please help me find the 66-character solution! I'm very very curious because I had to work really hard to bring mine down to 77, and I'm amazed as to how someone came up with a 66-character solution.

For reference, my solution:

```
for j in'x'*input():print'%.15f'%sum((-1)**i/(2.*i+1)for i in range(input()))
```

Comment: Very close to being a duplicate of [Calculate pi to 5 decimals](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7112/calculate-pi-to-5-decimals) (which has a Python solution, FWIW).

Comment: Sorry, I'm curious about a solution for this exact puzzle, not a related puzzle.

Comment: Suggest you read through [tips-for-golfing-in-python](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python). You can easily drop a few more chars

Comment: You should open it up to other languages and see how short people can program it :)

Comment: adr2370's solution is longer: https://github.com/adr2370/HackerRankBackToSchool/blob/master/Leibniz.py

Comment: Actually, it seems the top python solution wasn't really python, it was just a hack. So no one got a 66-character solution.

Comment: @Ari I'm very curious to know why you think the 66 characters solution was a hack.

Comment: For what it's worth, neither your solution nor any of the ones currently present in answers meet the stated specification. E.g. none of them give the correctly rounded answer of `0.785395663397448` for 100000 terms.

Comment: Can you include a description of what the code should do?  As it is, it's not clear what you're asking, as the requirements are hidden beyond a link, rather than in the body of the question.  (I tried following the link, but it's just a blank page, so not much help).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Python 71 bytes

```
exec"print'%.15g'%sum((-1.)**i/(i-~i)for i in range(input()));"*input()
```

Not quite 66 bytes, but with a score of 22.90, it would have ranked second overall.

**Edit**: regarding [Ari's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10716/#comment20257_10716) about the 66 byte Python solution being a 'hack', I don't think that's exactly what happened. I've noticed several times that the submitted language is displayed incorrectly. For example here: [Baconian Cipher](http://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/baconian-cipher/leaderboard). This challenge may only be submitted in Brainf_ck, yet the second ranked solution was submitted in Python 2 (interestingly enough, spot 23 is also Python 2. If I were to speculate, I would say that if the language information is missing from a submission for whatever reason, it seems to default to Python).

I suspect that a similar error may have occurred here, and that the shortest Python solution submitted during the challenge was actually 72 bytes.

**Update**: After speaking with a moderator, it seems that Ari was right:

[image]

Comment: Delightful hacks here!

Answer (score 6):

### Python, 65 characters

```
exec'print`sum((-1.)**x/(x-~x)for x in range(input()))`;'*input()
```

Comment: Interesting. The result of input `10`, for example, is not correctly rounded, but is still accepted as correct. Nice find.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 (50 chars, with input loop grows)

```
a=n=1.;s=0;exec's+=a/n;a=-a;n+=2;'*input();print s
```

also prints only 12 digits of result, with loop and formatting

```
exec input()*"a=n=1.;s=0;exec's+=a/n;a=-a;n+=2;'*input();print '%.15f'%s;"
```

74 chars

## Python 3 (57 chars, with input loop grows to 79 chars)

without loop

```
a=n=1;s=0;exec('s+=a/n;a=-a;n+=2;'*int(input()));print(s)
```

with loop

```
exec(int(input())*"a=n=1;s=0;exec('s+=a/n;a=-a;n+=2;'*int(input()));print(s);")
```

Python 3 prints 16 digits by default

```
exec(int(input())*"print(sum((-1)**i/(i-~i)for i in range(int(input()))));")
```

76 chars

Comment: A few problems: these don't iterate through a list of inputs (but rather only process a single input), and don't output the answer rounded to 15 decimal places (by default, Python only prints 12 digits of a float). Under these conditions, 49 bytes is possible, simply by removing the formatting and iteration from the accepted answer `print sum((-1.)**i/(i-~i)for i in range(input()))`